# JSON data not displaying using .html()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Before posting this question, I did search here and got different answers and I think it doesn't fit to my needs. I have a button when clicked, the following js script will run

```
$("#update-details-btn").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "confirmation="+get_data,
            url: '../for_update_details',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('div#update_details_body').html(data.results);
```

and this is the container

```
<div id="update_details_body" class="modal-body"></div>
```

the data comes from a php function

```
$data['results'] = NULL;
 $results = "<div class='form-group'>";
 $results .= "<label for='document-type' class='col-sm-4 control-label'>Category</label>";
 $results .= "</div>";
 $data['results'] = $results;
 echo json_encode($data);
```

As you can see from the js, I did a console.log which prints exactly what the data.results contain but when I use .html() to put inside the container, nothing happens. What could be the culprit here? I am doing this coding to other functions but only this section is not working

Comment: May be you need to `JSON.parse(data)` before `console.log`.

Comment: no need to parse he has `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: are you sure data is not binding to your div, i think the issue is of class="modal-body" its hidden somewhere

Comment: Hi @Rahul, the div is the modal body and this whole modal appears when the button is clicked

Comment: have you tried logging data.results instead of just data? is there any error?

Comment: @treecon yes I did. It shows the label and textbox but I am not able to see it in the container using.html. I don't know why but the method I am using here is the same to other functions in the app. Could this be a browser error'

Comment: if you skip the server side part and just create a variable with your JSON, then, does your .html() method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update-details-btn").on('click', function() {
        alert("inside");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'php_file.php',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('div#update_details_body').html(data.results);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<style>
.modal-body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="update_details_body" class="modal-body"></div>
<input type="button" id="update-details-btn" name="button" value="button">
</body>
</html>
```

php code not chnage

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Add this in success funtion. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

From your example I tink you dont need to parse data into json. simply echo `$results` and bind in ajax success

```
$("#update-details-btn").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',

            data: "confirmation="+get_data,
            url: '../for_update_details',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('div#update_details_body').html(data);
```

PHP:

```
$data['results'] = NULL;
 $results = "<div class='form-group'>";
 $results .= "<label for='document-type' class='col-sm-4 control-label'>Category</label>";
 $results .= "</div>";
echo $results;
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before the echo json_encode:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```